# optimizing simple Common Lisp gibbs sampler program

Tags: performance, statistics, common-lisp, sbcl, mcmc

As an exercise, I rewrote the example program in the blog post [Gibbs sampler in various languages (revisited)](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/gibbs-sampler-in-various-languages-revisited/) by Darren Wilkinson.

The code appears below. This code runs on my (5 year old) machine in around 53 seconds, using SBCL 1.0.56, creating a core image using buildapp, and then running it with

```
time ./gibbs > gibbs.dat
```

Since this was how the timings were calculated for the other languages in the post, I thought I would do something comparable
The C code in the post runs in around 25 seconds. I'd like to try and speed up the Lisp code if possible.

```
##############################
gibbs.lisp
##############################
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (require :cl-rmath) (setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float))

(defun gibbs (N thin)
  (declare (fixnum N thin))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 1)))
  (let ((x 0.0) (y 0.0))
    (declare (double-float x y))
    (print "Iter x y")
    (dotimes (i N)
      (dotimes (j thin)
    (declare (fixnum i j))
    (setf x (cl-rmath::rgamma 3.0 (/ 1.0 (+ (* y y) 4))))
    (setf y (cl-rmath::rnorm (/ 1.0 (+ x 1.0)) (/ 1.0 (sqrt (+ (* 2 x) 2))))))
      (format t "~a ~a ~a~%" i x y))))

(defun main (argv)
  (declare (ignore argv))
  (gibbs 50000 1000))
```

Then I built the executable `gibbs` with calling `sh gibbs.sh` with `gibbs.sh` as

```
##################
gibbs.sh
##################
buildapp --output gibbs --asdf-tree /usr/share/common-lisp/source/ --asdf-tree /usr/local/share/common-lisp/source/ --load-system cl-rmath --load gibbs.lisp --entry main
```

I get 6 compiler notes when compiling with SBCL 1.0.56, which reproduce below. I'm not sure what to do about them, but would be grateful for any hints.

```
; compiling file "/home/faheem/lisp/gibbs.lisp" (written 30 MAY 2012 02:00:55 PM):

; file: /home/faheem/lisp/gibbs.lisp
; in: DEFUN GIBBS
;     (SQRT (+ (* 2 X) 2))
; 
; note: unable to
;   optimize
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The result is a (VALUES (OR (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0) (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT))
;                           &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FLOAT &REST T).

;     (/ 1.0d0 (SQRT (+ (* 2 X) 2)))
; 
; note: unable to
;   optimize
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The second argument is a (OR (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0)
;                                (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT)), not a (COMPLEX
;                                                                DOUBLE-FLOAT).
; 
; note: forced to do static-fun Two-arg-/ (cost 53)
;       unable to do inline float arithmetic (cost 12) because:
;       The second argument is a (OR (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0) (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT)), not a DOUBLE-FLOAT.
;       The result is a (VALUES (OR (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT) (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0))
;                               &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES DOUBLE-FLOAT &REST T).

;     (CL-RMATH:RGAMMA 3.0d0 (/ 1.0d0 (+ (* Y Y) 4)))
; 
; note: doing float to pointer coercion (cost 13)

;     (SQRT (+ (* 2 X) 2))
; 
; note: doing float to pointer coercion (cost 13)

;     (CL-RMATH:RNORM (/ 1.0d0 (+ X 1.0d0)) (/ 1.0d0 (SQRT (+ (* 2 X) 2))))
; 
; note: doing float to pointer coercion (cost 13)
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 6 notes

; /home/faheem/lisp/gibbs.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.073
```

UPDATE 1: [Rainer Joswig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813558/350713) pointed out that the argument of the SQRT might be negative, which
was the source of the obscure compiler notes I was seeing, namely

```
The result is a (VALUES (OR (DOUBLE-FLOAT 0.0) (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT))
    ;                           &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FLOAT &REST T).
```

The compiler was complaining that since it didn't know whether the value of the argument was positive,
the result could be a complex number. Since in the example, the value `x` is a sample variate from the gamma distribution,
it is always greater than 0. It was helpfully pointed out by Stephan in the SBCL user mailing list,
(see second message in the thread ["Optimizing a simple Common Lisp Gibbs sampler program"](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.steel-bank.general/3543), that this could be resolved by declaring x to be greater than or zero as follows,

```
(declare (type (double-float 0.0 *) x))
```

See the Common Lisp Hyperspec for the relevant documentation about
[FLOAT types](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/t_short_.htm#double-float) 
and
[Interval Designators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/12_af.htm).

This seems to speed up the code a bit. It is now reliably below 52 seconds, but still, not much of a gain.
This also leaves the notes about

```
note: doing float to pointer coercion (cost 13)
```

If this is not fixable for some reason, I'd like to know why. Also, an explanation of what the note means would be interesting, regardless.
Specifically, what does the word `pointer` mean here? Is this related to the fact that C functions are being called? Also, cost 13 doesn't seem
very useful. What is being measured?

Also, Rainer suggested that it might be possible to reduce consing, which might reduce runtime. 
I don't know whether either consing reduction is possible, or whether it would reduce runtime,
but I'd be interested in opinions and approaches. Overall, it seems not much can be done to improve the performance of this function.
Maybe it is too small and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Common Lisp has a [THE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_the.htm#the) special operator. It allows you to declare types for expression results. This for example allows you to narrow down types if possible.

For example what is the result of `(SQRT somefloat)` ? It can be a float, but it could be a complex number if `somefloat` is negative. If you know that somefloat is always positive (and only then), then you could write `(the double-float (sqrt somefloat))`. The compiler then might be able to generate more efficient code.

Also note that Common Lisp has `OPTIMIZE` declarations. If you want fastest code you need to make sure that you set them accordingly. Possibly only for individual functions. Usually it is better than changing optimization globally to be very aggressive.

Common Lisp has a function `DISASSEMBLE` which lets you look at the compiled code.

Then there is the macro `TIME`. Interesting information you get from it includes how much consing it does. With double-float arithmetic there is probably a large amount of consing. It would be useful to ask on the SBCL mailing list for help. Maybe someone can tell you how to avoid that consing.

Comment: Hi, Rainer. Thanks for the comment, but I was hoping for something more specific. I'm already using `OPTIMIZE.` I tried using `THE`, but don't see where it would be useful except on the RHS of the `x` and `y` assignments, and in those cases, I would expect that the compiler could deduce that all those expressions, that derive from doubles, are themselves doubles. I did try it, but it doesn't make any noticeable difference. For lack of better ideas, I'd like to get rid of the compiler notes, but I don't understand what they are telling me.

Comment: I could also try profiling, but I'm not sure how useful it would be for such a small piece of code. Without any special declarations, I was getting slightly over 1 minute, and now I'm getting around 52 seconds, so the declarations haven't made much difference.

Comment: I'm still getting a compiler note about complex numbers. On further consideration, maybe it would be happy if i declared that `x` (or even `(+ (* 2 x) 2)`) was positive. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: I get `5,902,262,600 bytes consed`. That's a lot of consing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
(sqrt (the (double-float 0d0) (+ (* 2d0 x) 2d0)))
```

Comment: That does make the sqrt warnings disappear, but could you add an explanation, please? Thanks.